# Python DataFrame error for having a header with parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I am very new to python and programming in general. I have a CSV file that has the first column as string headers.

ie

```
time, speed(m/s), distance(m)
2,6,20
3,2,10

etc..
```

What I am trying to do is a program that will spit out a bunch of graphs based on my selection. for example time vs speed. or time vs speed and distance.

My first issue is whenever I try to graph something that has a parenthesis in its name for example:

```
df.Accel_Y(g).plot(color='r',lw=1.3)
```

I receive an error of:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Accel_Y'

It works fine if I try with a different column that has no parenthesis.

I tried to assign accel_y(g) to a letter for example z. Then doing this:

```
f.z.plot(color='r',lw=1.3)
```

that also didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Flight102_Complete.csv')
df.KestrelTime.plot(color='g',lw=1.3)
df.Accel_Y(g).plot(color='r',lw=1.3)
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider that accessing your columns via the `.` (dot) operator a privileged convenience.  It can break under many circumstances and sometimes silently so.  If you want to access the column do so with `[]` or `loc[]` or `iloc[]`.

Parenthesis are one of the conditions that will break the `.` accessor paradigm.

In your case
Don't do

```
df.Accel_Y(g).plot(color='r', lw=1.3)
```

Instead do

```
df['Accel_Y(g)'].plot(color='r', lw=1.3)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Do you have any guides on this subject manner i am very new to coding and python and some of the documentation I am reading for plotting I do not understand. I want to be able to do subplots of multiple columns so any noob friendly guide you know of that can help me that you can point out that would be awesome.

Comment: goto the wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info and look into the books at the bottom.  I bought Wes Mckinney's book.  Finding something you want to do and asking a lot of questions will do more for you than anything else.  Worry less about asking better questions and more about asking questions better.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/2336654